# Android Studio app works when I launch it from Android Studio, but not when I launch from device

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

I am new to app development and so far my app is working as intended but only when I launch it on my device from Android Studio. For example, I have once instance variable that I give a value of 1 in the onCreate() method. When I launch the app from android studio on to my device, it works fine and the variable has a value of 1. However, when I launch it from my device without using android studio, the variable is given a value of 0. I have also found that I will get a bunch of NullPointerExceptions on variables that I know should have a value, and once again it works when launched from Android Studio, but not when launched from the device.

Here is MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
private ArrayList<String> arrayList;
private ArrayList<ListItem> itemList;
private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
private EditText txtInput;
private int payRoll;
private String value;
private Intent mainToPayroll;
private int hours;
private int earnings;
private ArrayList<Integer> rollList;
private ArrayList<Integer> hourList;
private ArrayList<Integer> wageList;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    rollList = new ArrayList<>(0);
    hourList = new ArrayList<>(0);
    wageList = new ArrayList<>(0);
    payRoll = 1;

    Bundle bun = getIntent().getExtras();
    if(bun != null)
    {
        rollList = bun.getIntegerArrayList("rolls");
        hourList = bun.getIntegerArrayList("hours");
        wageList = bun.getIntegerArrayList("wages");
        payRoll = bun.getInt("roll");
    }

    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listv);
    String[] items = {};
    arrayList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(items));
    itemList = new ArrayList<>(0);
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, R.id.txtitem, arrayList);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    Button btAdd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btadd);
    mainToPayroll = new Intent(this, PayrollActivity.class);

    if(rollList != null)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < rollList.size(); i++) {
            ListItem newItem = new ListItem(rollList.get(i), hourList.get(i), wageList.get(i));
            arrayList.add(newItem.toString());
            itemList.add(newItem);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }


        rollList.clear();
        hourList.clear();
        wageList.clear();
    }

    btAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            ListItem newItem = new ListItem(payRoll, 0, 0);
            arrayList.add(newItem.toString());
            itemList.add(newItem);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            payRoll++;
        }
    });

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
        {
            value = (String)adapter.getItem(position);
            ListItem item = itemList.get(position);
            Bundle info = new Bundle();
            info.putString("val", value);
            info.putInt("hours", item.getHours());
            info.putInt("wage", item.getWages());
            info.putInt("pos", position);

            if(itemList.size() > 0)
            {
                for (ListItem items : itemList)
                {
                    rollList.add(items.getPayroll());
                    hourList.add(items.getHours());
                    wageList.add(items.getWages());
                }
            }

            info.putIntegerArrayList("rolls", rollList);
            info.putIntegerArrayList("hours", hourList);
            info.putIntegerArrayList("wages", wageList);
            info.putInt("roll", payRoll);
            info.putBoolean("rest", restore);


            mainToPayroll.putExtras(info);

            startActivity(mainToPayroll);
        }
    });
}
```

This Activity is started whenever an item on the listview is clicked

```
public class PayrollActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
private static TextView text;
private String payrollNumber;
private int payrollHrs;
private int payrollWages;
private int position;
private Intent payrollToMain;
private Button returnButton;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_payroll);

    final Bundle info = getIntent().getExtras();
    System.out.print(getIntent().getType());
    payrollNumber = info.getString("val");
    payrollHrs = info.getInt("hours");
    payrollWages = info.getInt("wage");
    position = info.getInt("pos");
    payrollToMain = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    returnButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnRtrn);

    returnButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            Bundle thing = new Bundle();
            thing.putIntegerArrayList("rolls", info.getIntegerArrayList("rolls"));
            thing.putIntegerArrayList("hours", info.getIntegerArrayList("hours"));
            thing.putIntegerArrayList("wages", info.getIntegerArrayList("wages"));
            thing.putInt("roll", info.getInt("roll"));
            thing.putBoolean("rest", info.getBoolean("rest"));
            payrollToMain.putExtras(thing);
            startActivity(payrollToMain);

        }
    });

    text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.title);

    text.setText(payrollNumber);
}

public static void setLabelText(String val)
{
    text.setText(val);
}
```

This is a class I created for the items that go on the listview

```
public class ListItem
{
private int payroll;
private int hrs;
private int wages;

public ListItem(int roll, int hours, int wag)
{
    payroll = roll;
    hrs = hours;
    wages = wag;
}

public int getPayroll()
{
    return payroll;
}

public int getHours()
{
    return hrs;
}

public int getWages()
{
    return wages;
}

public void setPayroll(int roll)
{
    payroll = roll;
}

public void setHrs(int hours)
{
    hrs = hours;
}

public void setWages(int wage)
{
    wages = wage;
}

public String toString()
{
    return "Payroll " + payroll + "\n" + hrs + " hours\n$" + wages;
}
```

Comment: Are you using Instant Run?

Comment: Show us some code, without it we can't help you

Comment: Yes, I am using instant run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem is this piece of code in your MainActivity:

```
Bundle bun = getIntent().getExtras();
if(bun != null)
{
    rollList = bun.getIntegerArrayList("rolls");
    hourList = bun.getIntegerArrayList("hours");
    wageList = bun.getIntegerArrayList("wages");
    payRoll = bun.getInt("roll");
}
```

The `getIntent().getExtras()` may return a non-null `Bundle` object but the bundle may not have the keys you are trying to access, in which case all your instance variables will be set to null or zero for `int`.

You can get around this by simply checking if a particular key exists in the bundle and only setting your variable if it does.

[`bun.containsKey()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/BaseBundle.html#containsKey(java.lang.String))

Or you can initialize your variables if they are null after loading them from the bundle.

Comment: Thanks for the response, this seems to have fixed the problem and the app now works as intended both when launched through android studio and from my device. This was really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Try uninstalling the app completely from the device and then try again. This solves the issue at times.

Comment: I have tried that but I did not work. I will keep trying it though until it either works, or I find another solution. Thanks for the reply.